# XML node and text value. Is this right?

Tags: javascript, xml, nodes

I have the following bit of XML. 2 questions which I can seem to anwser: Is it valid XML? (To have a value and children nodes inside 'FOO'. Question 2 (The more important one), How do I access the 'TEXT' value and the 'BOO' node separately in JavaScript?

```
<FOO>
    TEXT
    <BOO>
    </BOO>
    <BOO>
    </BOO>
</FOO>
```

Tried .firstChild.nodeValue and this works fine. (Returned the value of TEXT) however the problem occurs if TEXT is null. It returns a [Object Element] instead (the BOO node). So basically - I want to get the TEXT text if its there, if not I want to get null, or equivalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a valid XML.
This are some basic rule for a valid XML:

- XML documents must have a root element
- XML elements must have a closing tag
- XML tags are case sensitive
- XML elements must be properly nested
- XML attribute values must be quoted

Having this XML document:

```
<CATALOG>
  VERSION_1
  <CD>
    <TITLE>Empire Burlesque</TITLE>
    <ARTIST>Bob Dylan</ARTIST>
    <COUNTRY>USA</COUNTRY>
    <COMPANY>Columbia</COMPANY>
    <PRICE>10.90</PRICE>
    <YEAR>1985</YEAR>
   </CD>
   <CD>
     <TITLE>Hide your heart</TITLE>
     <ARTIST>Bonnie Tyler</ARTIST>
     <COUNTRY>UK</COUNTRY>
     <COMPANY>CBS Records</COMPANY>
     <PRICE>9.90</PRICE>
     <YEAR>1988</YEAR>
   </CD>
</CATALOG>
```

You can access the document in JavaScript using some code like this:

```
x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CD");
i=0;

function displayCD()
{
   // What you want here --->
   textInRootElemnt=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CATALOG")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;


   artist=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("ARTIST")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   title=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TITLE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   year=(x[i].getElementsByTagName("YEAR")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
   txt="Artist: " + artist + "<br />Title: " + title + "<br />Year: "+ year;
   document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML=txt;
}
```

Where xmlDoc is your loaded document.

Consider the following very basic [*tutorial*](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/default.asp)  about XML.

Comment: Thanks for the basic tutorial - Clearly didn't make myself clear enough. Sorry. Have edited my question now.

Comment: @User2 consider my edited code.
`xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("CATALOG")[0].childNodes` return all the text nodes and the elements nodes. If your xml is formated so you have and `\n` or `\n\r` value there plus indentation your first child will be always this value then, for exemple 'VERSION_1' (if there is some text) and if not you will have the element node.

Comment: Actually with this method you always will have a textNode then an elementNode, following the test I just made!

Comment: I'm accepting your answer because it was the most helpful. However, I think the value of 'textInRootElemnt' would be the CD node in your example (If the text 'VERSION_1' wasn't there). I found another way to do it in the end. Still helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is valid xml.

Please rephrase your question clearly :
 How do I access the *'TEXT' and the* separately in JavaScript?